# textView breaking lines automatically - Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, textview, horizontal-scrolling

I'm trying to populate a textView with the content of an array. For each item in my array i have a flag setting true or false for this item, if its true i copy the content in a var called "nome" to the textview.
I did this with the code below:

```
    for item in lista {
        if item.disp == true {   //checking if its true
            var tempString = "\(item.nome)\n"   //concatenate string with the a new line
            textView_Lista_Pecas.text! += tempString    //set the textView text
        }
    }
```

... the string printed must be shown line by line, but as it is a long  string, the textView break the line when the string texts gets to the edge of textView.

I tried to enabled the horizontal scrollview to maximize the size of the textView, but only the vertical one is enabled when i check the option.
Anyone could give me a hint on this? I'm using swift and xcode 6.3.1.

Comment: Can you use UITextField?

Comment: As far as i know, UITextField is supposed to be an one-line object. What's your idea?

Comment: UITextField won't wrap. If you have only one line, it would be adequate for your use.

Comment: ... i have a lot of lines. And i need to use lines to list the items.